# How threshold images with texture? Recognition by tesseract

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, threshold

Source image:

[image]

Destination image:

[image]

Code:

```
cv::Mat sharpenedLena;
cv::Mat kernel = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0);
cv::filter2D(matGrey, sharpenedLena, matGrey.depth(), kernel);
cv::adaptiveThreshold(sharpenedLena, matBinary, 255,    cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, 55, 30);
cv::Mat dst_img1;
//cv::GaussianBlur(matBinary, dst_img1, cv::Size(3,3), 0, 0);
cv::medianBlur(matBinary, dst_img1, 3);

UIImage *addrUIImage = [ImageUtil UIImageFromCVMat:dst_img1];
[self recognizeImageWithTesseract:addrUIImage withLauange:1];
```

Result:

> 三胡南省慈利昙龙三覃河镇文

I think it should be a picture deal with the problem. Here there is a treatment effect of others. How to achieve this effect?

Target image:

[image]

Comment: What is the image resolution you are working with? Higher resolution images are advised for best OCR results.

Comment: I know，But using a mobile phone camera, a large environmental factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my results & Code Snippet:
[image]

```
Mat mSource_Bgr,mSource_Gray,mSource_Hsv,mThreshold;
mSource_Bgr= imread(FileName_S.c_str(),1);

namedWindow("Source Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Source Image",mSource_Bgr);

cvtColor(mSource_Bgr,mSource_Hsv,COLOR_BGR2HSV);

mSource_Hsv = mSource_Hsv + Scalar(0,0,-25); //Subtracting 25 from all the Pixel Values
cvtColor(mSource_Hsv,mSource_Bgr,COLOR_HSV2BGR);// Back to BGR Just for Debug purpose
```

[image]

```
imshow("Improved Darkness",mSource_Bgr);
imwrite(FileName_S+"_Res.bmp",mSource_Bgr);

cvtColor(mSource_Bgr,mSource_Gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // for Adaptive Thresholding the input Image

adaptiveThreshold(mSource_Gray,mThreshold,255,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,THRESH_BINARY,59,10);
```

[image]

```
imshow("Adaptive Thres",mThreshold);
imwrite(FileName_S+"_Thres.bmp",mThreshold);
```

You can remove the Noise i.e small dots by using contour Area or by Morphological Processing.Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thand you!Indeed been greatly improved.    cv::Mat kernel2(3, 3, CV_8UC1, 0);
    cv::morphologyEx(matBinary, matBinary, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2, cv::Point(1, 1), 1);

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [adaptiveThreshold()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold) or algorithms such as [MSER](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcmp.felk.cvut.cz%2F~matas%2Fpapers%2Fmatas-bmvc02.pdf&ei=cbI4VZKdHYf7auGHgKAF&usg=AFQjCNGXv1k27m9V0t21Q89ogVqZLvtvYQ&sig2=DW0dNzTy0sWrVTxFSgUy3g&bvm=bv.91427555,d.d2s) [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#mser).

These will perform better, especially MSER and its variant CSER are designed to detect text-like structures.

Comment: I am now using adaptiveThreshold() ,I do not know how to start，Achieve the effect of the third picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Binary thresholding with a OPEN Morphology operation.